# Is it possible to update value in the collection in the query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am not sure whether the title explains what I try to say.

But here assume collection's structure is like;

```
[
    {email: "alex@sda.com"},
    {email: "elizabeth@sds.com"},
    {email: "hannah@xx.com"},
]
```

I want to get emails but before the `@` character.

What have I done to achieve this?

```
db.collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, result){
    var emails = [];    
    for(var i =0; i< result.length; i++){
         emails.push(result[i].split("@")[0]);
    }
})
```

But I don't find this efficient because after the query, I loop through the result and store them in new array.

Is there a better way to get only the `alex`, `elizabeth`, `hannah` parth with a query?

This is just an example. I want to ask your suggestions because I have lots of situations like this. (I am looking for a most efficient way to trim, update some values in the collections)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[`distinct`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#distinct)** method first to get the list of email addresses then use regex to get the names:

```
db.collection.distinct("email", function(err, result){
    var emails = result.map(function(email){
        return email.match(/^([^@]*)@/)[1];
    });
    console.log(emails);
});
```

---

With the aggregation framework, MongoDB 3.4 has a **[`$split`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/#exp._S_split)** operator that you can use in conjunction with **[`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#exp._S_arrayElemAt)**:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "emails": {
                "$push": {
                    "$arrayElemAt": [
                        { "$split": ["$email", "@"] },
                        0
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }   
], function(err, result){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    /*
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "emails" : [ 
                "alex", 
                "elizabeth", 
                "hannah"
            ]
        }   
    */
});
```

Comment: Oh yeah. I didn't know the `$split`. Thank you. I think MongoDB 3.4  brought a lot of convenience.

Comment: True, it has quite a number of useful features in the aggregation framework that go a long way!